# How would I perform this SQL query with subselect in Slick?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, subquery, slick

```sql
select
    *,
    (select count(1) from variants as v where v.product_id = p.id) as variants
from
    products as p
;
```

The query gives the results I want, so I just need to be able to do the same from Slick now. I have `Product` and `Variant` models with corresponding `Products` and `Variants` tables and `products` and `variants` `TableQuery`s set up.

This is what I ended up with:

```scala
products.map(product =>
            (product, variants.filter(_.productId === product.id).length)
        ) map (_ <> (ProductAndVariantCount.tupled, ProductAndVariantCount.unapply))
```

Comment: You can always use raw SQL interpolators: http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/sql.html#result-sets . Raw SQL becomes much easier to handle once your use case becomes even remotely more complex than CRUD a single entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic form would be:

```
products.map(row => 
  (row.id, row.otherColumnsHere, variants.filter(_.product_id === row.id).length)
)
```

The way I approach these problems is to turn each part of a query into a Slick expression, and see how they might combine.

In your case, the thinking was:

- the sub-select is, something like `table.filter(...).length`
- the main select is `table.map(...)`
- and then see if I can get them to combine in some way.

Comment: Thanks! That got me where I needed to be (see updated question).